# http post :NullPointerException

Tags: java, http, http-post, httpurlconnection

I am new to Java and am supposed to send an XML file to HTTP server. The XML file should be converted to string first:

I am getting the error from the server :

```
[stdout] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1) failed in postjava.lang.NullPointerException

[stdout] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1) received post request :
```

It seems I am sending nothing to the server.

**Here is the code**

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLEncoder;
import java.util.Scanner;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.*;
import javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMSource;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;


public class try_post {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try{
            BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));


            DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();

            Document doc = builder.parse("D:\\n.xml");
            StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter(); 

            Transformer transformer =TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer(); 

            transformer.transform(new DOMSource(doc), new StreamResult(stringWriter)); 
            String strFileContent = stringWriter.toString();  
            System.out.println(strFileContent);
            System.out.println( strFileContent.getClass().getName());
            System.out.println("xml file converted to string"); 

            String param="param1=" + URLEncoder.encode(strFileContent ,"UTF-8");

            URL url = new URL("http://localhost:8080/");
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            connection.setDoOutput(true);
            //      connection.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);
            connection.setRequestMethod("POST");

            connection.setFixedLengthStreamingMode(param.getBytes().length);
            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

            OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream());

            writer.write(param);
            writer.flush();

            String line;
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));

            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(line);
            }
            writer.close();
            reader.close();

            String response= "";


            StreamSource source = new StreamSource(fileReader);
            StreamResult result = new StreamResult(os);
            transformer.transform(source, result);*/



            DataOutputStream fos = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream ());

            System.out.println("Response code: " + connection.getResponseCode());
            connection.disconnect();}
        catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
            System.out.print("MalformedURLException");

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.print(" Exception: "+ex.getMessage());

        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

No one can help based on what you've posted.  The stack trace has to have more than this.

There are lots of things wrong with your code:

1. Print the stack trace, not just the message.  It'll have more information.
2. You use the connection object without checking to see if it's null first.  That could be it.
3. Same with that Document object.  How do you know that the XML was read?

Looks like you're trying to read XML from a file and POST it to a servlet listening on your localhost.  You just check the response code.  What did I miss?

You aren't nearly defensive enough for my taste.  No wonder you're having problems.

Print the stack trace, like this:

```
    catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Another smart thing to try is to run in an IDE like IntelliJ and step through your code with a debugger.  You'll see why you're getting a NPE in less time than you've waited for answers here.

Comment: I asked the question to get what I am doing wrong..I do not understand your post!! what do u mean by stack trace? the only feed back I am getting from the server is [stdout] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1) failed in postjava.lang.NullPointerException

[stdout] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1) received post request

Comment: I'm saying that you should be getting more than that, and I told you how.  Print - the - stack - trace.

Comment: on the server side(command line) ,I am only getting this error:[stdout] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1) failed in postjava.lang.NullPointerException [stdout] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1) received post request

Comment: @lujain - So... Change your code so that you print the stack trace rather than **ONLY** printing the exception's message.  In other words, in stead of printing `ex.getMessage()`, you should call `ex.printStackTrace()`.  Then you'll see a big, long stack trace that will tell you the **EXACT** line of code that threw the NullPointerException.  This is how you debug a NullPointerException (at least this is one way to do it... using a debugger would be better).

Comment: I am not getting any exception:the output is the content of the xml file and java.lang.String
xml file converted to string
Response code: 204

Comment: Read this, then: http://benramsey.com/blog/2008/05/http-status-204-no-content-and-205-reset-content/  Sounds like you need to run the debugger on the servlet, not the main client.

Answer (score 2):

Oh, I see. Just use Ruby.

```
require "net/http"; require "uri"
params = { param1: File.read("D:\\n.xml") }
uri = URI.parse("http://localhost:8080/")
resp = Net::HTTP.post_form(uri, params)
puts "Response code: #{resp.code}"
```

Sorry, I had to do it. * Braces for downvotes *

Answer (score 1):

The exception is happening on the server side, not in your code. Is the exception stack trace logged on the server? You may need to look at the server-side code to debug this.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see, your doing things the hard way. Try using HTTPClient library.
This should simplify your code alot.

For the maven dependency see:
http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Ccommons-httpclient%7Ccommons-httpclient%7C3.1%7Cjar

For a working code example see:
See: http://www.kodejava.org/browse/47.html